# Getting date of week of year

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I want to get start date of week from its number with following code:

```
+ (NSDate *)dateOfWeek:(NSInteger)weekOfYear year:(NSInteger)year {

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [calendar setFirstWeekday:2]; // monday
    calendar.minimumDaysInFirstWeek = 4; // iso 8601

    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    components.year = year;
    components.weekOfYear = weekOfYear;
    [components setWeekday:2]; // monday

    NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

    return date;
}
```

If year = 2017 and weekOfYear = 52 (or other valid numbers) date is correct:

```
2017-12-24 21:00:00 +0000
```

if year = 2018 and weekOfYear = 2 date is correct too:

```
2018-01-07 21:00:00 +0000
```

but if year = 2018 and weekOfYear = 1 date is incorrect:

```
2018-12-30 21:00:00 +0000
```

it must be **2017-12-31 21:00:00 +0000**.

---

There is a second way to get dates using NSDateFormatter:

```
NSString    *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li %li", (long)year, (long)weekOfYear];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy ww";

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"%@", [date description]);
```

But it works with the same problems with year = 2018 and weekOfYear = 1!

---

What I`m doing wrong with getting week dates or this is Foundation bug?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a Foundation bug.

You need the component `yearForWeekOfYear` to get the correct week of year:

```
components.yearForWeekOfYear = year;
```

The date formatter issue is actually the same, the *yearForWeekOfYear* specifier is `Y`

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"YYYY ww";
```

Comment: Thank you, you made my day :) But it is not solve same problem with NSDateFormatter way...

Comment: "The ISO 8601 definition for week 01 is the week with the Gregorian year's first Thursday in it." -- [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)
That's the reason we should use `yearForWeekOfYear`, just found this bug in my App in the first week of the new year :)